# Finding the character presence in a String :java

Tags: java, android, char, hex, uri

I am trying to create a method in Java that does the equivalent to

`'Uri.IsHexDigit(char)'` in C#. I want to check whether a character is in a set of char arrays to see if it a correct character. Please could anyone look at my code and see what I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

Here is my code so far:

```
public boolean hexChecker(char c)
{
    String string = "0123456789abcdefABCDEF";
    char[] charArray = string.toCharArray();

    for(char ch : charArray)
    {
        if(c == ch)
        {
            System.out.println("It worked!");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("It did not work!");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make life easy. Simply

```
   public boolean hexChecker(char c) {
        String string = "0123456789abcdefABCDEF";
        return string.indexOf(c) > -1;
    }
```

Comment: what does it mean: "> -1". can you please explain this. does it have something to do with if the char c is not found in the string?

Comment: @AbhinavRaja You are on right spot. please check indexOf method  docs for more clarification

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex:

```
private final static Patter phex = Pattern.compile("[0-9A-F]+");

public boolean hexCharacter(char c) {
   return phex.matcher("" + c).matches();
}
```